# How to run Android Studio on Win XP?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to development for android and new to Android Studio. But I used to develop on Java with Eclipse. However, since I got an Android phone I thought it would be fun to develop an app for it. But I ran into some problems at once.

My hardware is an old Compaq 6910p. The OS is Windows XP.

I downloaded the latest Android Studio and the Java version is 1.8.

But When I start the Android Studio I get the following error (some problem with the adb, that I guess must be running?):

[image: Error upon starting Android Studio]

If I try to start the adb.exe from command line I get this error:

[image: Error upon starting adb from command line]

My Android Studio and the environment information is as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: If you follow the duplicate link you will see that only version `1.X` of Android Studio ever supported Windows XP.  You might want to upgrade your OS, since there may be limitations to working with such an old version of Android Studio.

Comment: @user2902165                                                                                       Please go to this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio            On this page there are tips that will help you.                                           You have to use Android Studio versions 1.x and JDK versions 7.